# SPD 2010 Workflow update Calendar list based on Condition

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, designer-workflow

I have created a InfoPath 2010 form + SPD 2010 multi-level workflow(Leave Authorisation Form). The infopath form is stored on a Forms library(Leave Authorisation forms Library) once it is submitted and then the workflow kicks off. Once the workflow is Approved I want to Add an Item in to Leave Calendar(Calendar LIST). But before inserting item I want to check if it already exist or not based on date range. SPD workflow has options to Create list item but I don't see an option to check for date range on a list.

To overcome this limitation I have created a Event Receiver on the list and when the status changes to "approved" I'll create an Item on a leave calendar.

Is there any other alternate approach other than using Event Receiver?

Comment: Hi Kannabiran dd you got any solution for your query.I have the same scenario for me can you please provide if you got any solution for this.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can delete all items in that leave calendar. then you can create all leave requests into the calendar again.

Comment: You didn't understand my question.